# html_attr "href" returns NA in rvest

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping, rvest

My goal is to extract the urls associated with a specific css elements in a website using `rvest`. After looking at several other similar questions, I think I will need to use the `html_attr` function with the `'href'` argument. With my present script this only returns `NA` values, although I would expect it to return urls.

**Input to build variables**

```
library(rvest)

my_url <- "http://www.sherdog.com/events/UFC-Fight-Night-111-Holm-vs-Correia-58241"

my_read_url <- read_html(my_url)

my_nodes <- html_nodes(my_read_url, ".fighter_result_data a span , .right_side a span , .left_side a span")
```

**Input to see if `my_nodes`are coming from the names of the athletes.**

```
html_text(my_nodes)
```

**Output showing `my_nodes` are selecting the css elements I desire.**

```
[1] "Holly Holm"          "Bethe Correia"       "Marcin Tybura"      
 [4] "Andrei Arlovski"     "Colby Covington"     "Dong Hyun Kim"      
 [7] "Rafael dos Anjos"    "Tarec Saffiedine"    "Jon Tuck"           
[10] "Takanori Gomi"       "Walt Harris"         "Cyril Asker"        
[13] "Alex Caceres"        "Rolando Dy"          "Yuta Sasaki"        
[16] "Justin Scoggins"     "Jingliang Li"        "Frank Camacho"      
[19] "Russell Doane"       "Kwan Ho Kwak"        "Naoki Inoue"        
[22] "Carls John de Tomas" "Lucie Pudilova"      "Ji Yeon Kim"
```

**Input to try to get the urls to each of the athletes' unique pages.**

```
html_attr(my_nodes, "href")
```

**Output showing that my attempt only returns a list of `NA` values**

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Can anyone help me actually obtain the urls instead of these `NA` values? Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You are selecting the `span` elements, not the `a` elements in your `html_nodes` command. The `span` elements do not have an `href=` attribute, only the `a` elements do. Instead use

```
my_nodes <- html_nodes(my_read_url, ".fighter_result_data a, .right_side a, .left_side a")
html_text(my_nodes)
html_attr(my_nodes, "href")
```

Comment: This gets 99% of the way there.

The `html_text(my_nodes)` now has oddities at indices 1 and 3.

Anyway to create a `my_nodes` variable with css elements which produces both the specific list of athletes I am interested in, without the odd indices, and the correct urls?

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, this helped to make me unstuck! I was trying to use 'a' in the beginning, as in ".a name" but that didn't work for some reason. Putting the 'a' at the end worked!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @MrFlick answer, the links are present in `<a>` you have to access it.

```
my_url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('.fighter_result_data') %>% html_nodes('a') %>% 
  html_attr('href')
[1] "/fighter/Marcin-Tybura-86928"        "/fighter/Andrei-Arlovski-270"
```